# get rid of "No Caching mode page found" message during boot

Tags: kernel, logs, startup, console

during early boot, I get following error message:

```
[sdb] No Caching mode page found
[sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

If I understand correctly, this is actually just a harmless info message and not an actual error. `sdb` is my USB disk, and it does not use caching .

The problem is, I have intentionally set kernel loglevel to 4, to get rid of these kind of useless info messages.

Why then do I still get this info message?

The reason why it's bothering me is, that it interferes with my password prompt (for decrypting my LUKS disk)

**Is there a way to get rid of this message ?**

Comment: Use a lower kernel parameter eg `loglevel=0` to tailor linux messaging levels. I think level 4 is too high to silence this specific message. Level 0 is probably too drastic, but it does get rid of ALL annoying system puke in the middle of my sweet, sweet boot screens.

Answer (score 12):

Hard disks have a small amount of RAM cache to speed up write operations. The system can write a chunk of data to the disk cache without actually waiting for it to be written to the disk. This is sometimes called "write-back" mode.
If there is no cache on the disk, data is directly written to it in "write-through" mode.
The Asking for cache data failed warning usually occurs with devices such as USB flash drives, USB card readers, etc. which present themselves as SCSI devices to the system (sdX), but have no cache.
The system asks the device: "Do you have a cache?" and gets no response. So it assumes there is no cache and puts it in "write-through" mode.

You may try to go to:

```
/etc/modules
```

and on top of the modules list add the line

```
usb_storage
```

It should look something like this:

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

usb_storage
lp
```

This is how I solved a similar problem.

Let me know what happened.

Comment: I am not sure what problem this is supposed to solve. But it is not applicable to my problem. Besides, I don't use modules in my kernel.

Comment: It did not fix it

Comment: @malyy I wonder what's "lp" is in the last line. What it stand for?

Comment: I tried this, but still have the message.  ld appears to have made the listing more detailed.

Comment: It doesn't work when usb_storage is not a dedicated module but built into the kernel: `# modinfo usb_storage` > `name: usb_storage; filename: (builtin)`

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can get rid of such messages by executing following command:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

This will suppress almost all the kernel messages and will display only Emergency messages

See [this](http://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing#Log_Levels) link for more info

Comment: Probably because this will not have effect during _early_ bootup, before any userspace takes control. Same setting will have effect by adding `loglevel=0` to kernel command line from bootloader (by editing and applying bootloader configuration before next reboot). P.S. I did not down voted, just FYI.

Comment: I mean under `userspace control` is that `echo` command that does write to `/proc/sys/kernel/printk` pseudofile.

Comment: OP can add above echo command in his one of initramfsfs hooks or scripts.

Comment: @SHW - I don't want to suppress all kernel messages. My question is explicitly "how can I get rid of **this** message". Besides, I stated in my original post that I am using  kernel parameter `loglevel=4`. I could just change that to `loglevel=5` to get rid of almost all messages, but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a warn message (maybe the driver considers it important enough to mention).  You did not specify which driver your USB hard drive is using so I can't point to the source line to verify this.  More info on log levels here: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/kern_levels.h?id=HEAD

The easiest fix would be adding "quiet" to your kernel arguments via the bootloader, whether it's GRUB/LILO/etc.

Comment: I can confirm I get this message logged at "err" in syslog.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a new Arch Linux UEFI installation where I was using a UEFI Live USB to load the bootloader on the `ESP`.

The solution was to fix the setup with an **EFI Boot Manager**.

- From Windows an easy solution is [easyuefi](https://www.easyuefi.com/)
- From Linux use [`efibootmgr`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFISTUB#efibootmgr) & set a [`timeout` value](https://www.lifewire.com/change-the-efi-boot-order-efibootmgr-4028027)

If you use `GRUB` & not an [`EFISTUB`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFISTUB) to boot Linux you do **NOT** need to add any `crypt` kernel commands to the `efibootmgr` commands.